# Accessing GnuCash sql from Linux doesn't work anymore

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb, gnucash

I have a GnuCash database on a mariadb-server, which was set up with a copy of GnuCash from an Ubuntu 16.04 client, and all has been working well.

Then I decided to test GnuCash from a Windows 10-machine towards my GnuCash database, which works well, but now whenever I try to access the database from GnuCash on a Linux machine (tested Lubuntu, Ubuntu, Mint) I can log in to the database, but it freezes as soon as I try to edit or add a transaction.

There is no stacktrace present and I cannot find a logfile anywhere. Can anyone please help me get further with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue: Version.

The version of GnuCash I used on the Windows 10-machine was `2.6.19`, whilst the version I used on the Linux-machines was `2.6.12`.

It appears that when you use a new(er) version of GnuCash towards a database, GnuCash updates the database to support the new version and (in my case) broke legacy support for version `2.6.12`. When I downloaded the most recent source and compiled it on the Linux-machines, it all worked again.

Remember kids, always keep track of what version of software you are using.